# NullPointerExceptions in BlameGenerator when executing sonar-runner

Tags: java, git, jgit

This is not a new problem but it still occurs in jGit 4.4.1.

I have a problem with NullPointerExceptions in BlameGenerator for some files (5 in total) when executing sonar-runner via Jenkins.

I downloaded and tried the latest jgit version to see if the error was reproducable:

`$ /c/Users/ebiesse/Downloads/org.eclipse.jgit.pgm-4.4.1.201607150455-r.sh --version
jgit version 4.4.1.201607150455-r`

and it gave the same root cause as the Jenkins job, so I guess the problem is in jgit:

```
$ /c/Users/ebiesse/Downloads/org.eclipse.jgit.pgm-4.4.1.201607150455-r.sh  blame -w services/document-definition-service-client-impl/src/main/java/com/streamserve/service/client/document/definition/request/GetDocumentDefinitionRequest.java
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.eclipse.jgit.blame.BlameGenerator.getSourceStart(BlameGenerator.java:870)
        at org.eclipse.jgit.blame.BlameResult.loadFrom(BlameResult.java:338)
        at org.eclipse.jgit.blame.BlameResult.computeAll(BlameResult.java:240)
        at org.eclipse.jgit.blame.BlameResult.computeRange(BlameResult.java:294)
        at org.eclipse.jgit.pgm.Blame.run(Blame.java:195)
        at org.eclipse.jgit.pgm.TextBuiltin.execute(TextBuiltin.java:199)
        at org.eclipse.jgit.pgm.Main.execute(Main.java:246)
        at org.eclipse.jgit.pgm.Main.run(Main.java:138)
        at org.eclipse.jgit.pgm.Main.main(Main.java:110)
```

In this particular directory there are 3 more java files, and they are all fine.

- Is there anything I could do to make the failing files go through?
- The git-repo is quite big. If I should pack it and send it, would there be a possibility to pack just a part of it?

Kind regards,
Erika

Comment: Can you try to find out in what the failing files differ from the succeeding ones? E.g. are those new files without history, or empty, or...

Comment: @RüdigerHerrmann I cannot see any pattern here. Looking just at the files in this particular directory, they are very similar, and super-short, less than 40 lines. 'git log' show they have all at least one check-in in history, but less than 7. The failing one has been merged twice, in both cases both versions seem to have identical edits in both branches merged. They have not been edited since 2012...

Comment: Is any of the. commits on the failing files without author or committer?

Comment: Could you create a repository to reproduce the problem?

Comment: @RüdigerHerrmann Using gitk I can see both author and committer, they are both set for all commits.
Create a repository - do you have a suggestion on how to do it?

Comment: From looking at the stack trace, it seems as if there is no current/further blame data available when `getSourceStart()` is called. To verify this, however, a repository or a test case to reproduce would be needed.

Comment: I have now produced a packed file from a very limited part of my repo which I can import to a new repo with 'git fast-import' and then reproduce the error. I reported a bug on jgit, Bug 499543. Hope I will get some response.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to report the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is JGit bugzilla 499543, and still occurs in JGit 4.6.0 (SonarQube Git plugin 1.3).  https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=499543

Answer (score 0):

I ran the command line test with the latest JGit 4.11 release and CentOS 7.4.
The problem is basically still there, but the stack trace is significantly different:

```
$ ../../org.eclipse.jgit.pgm-4.11.0.201803080745-r.sh blame  -w  \ 
    src/main/java/Package/Name/And/File.java
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.eclipse.jgit.pgm.Blame.run(Blame.java:193)
        at org.eclipse.jgit.pgm.TextBuiltin.execute(TextBuiltin.java:228)
        at org.eclipse.jgit.pgm.Main.execute(Main.java:278)
        at org.eclipse.jgit.pgm.Main.run(Main.java:166)
        at org.eclipse.jgit.pgm.Main.main(Main.java:138)
```

Removing the  -w  option no longer has any effect on the results.
Using an absolute path instead of a relative path also does not effect the results.